# Make HTTP request to wait for specific property in response

Tags: node.js, angular, api

I have standard http.post request to an external API of my parcel delivery company. Unfortunately sometimes when I'm adding a new parcel, the response that should contain tracking number returns this property as null.
I figured out that it needs a period of time to generate it so I add timeout and wrote it like that:

```
this.order.id = '11111111'

const data:any = {
  //object of parcel        
}


this.addParcel(data) //POST request
  .subscribe(
    response => {
      //this returns parcel object with id that is needed to get tracking_number
      setTimeout( () =>
        this.getTrackingNumber(response.id) //GET request
          .subscribe(
            response2 => {
              const shipment = {
                waybill: response2.tracking_number,
              }
              this.addTrackingNumber(this.order.id, shipment)
                .subscribe(
                  response3 => {
                    console.log('success', response3);
                  },
                  error => console.log('oops', error)
                );
            },
            error => console.log('oops', error)
          ),
      1000);
    },
    error => console.log('oops', error)
  );
```

And in most cases it working as expected but sometimes getTrackingNumber() function returns

> tracking_number

property with null because time that it needs to generate it is not specified.

So there is my question:
Is there any possible way to force http request to wait for tracking_number property to be not null?

I was also thinking of calling it again if it returns tracking_number:null but i don't think this is a good practice.
Unfortunately setTimeout is also not ideal solution beacause period of time needed generate tracking_number is different, sometimes it takes practically no time and sometimes even over the given 1000ms.

In this project I'm using Angular and Nest.js so I have option to write it also on frontend or backend side.

Thanks for any ideas.

Greetings.